# How to handle two kernel recipes in parallel?

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto

We have got one build-config for a couple of similar images. They differ in development and deployment recipes. We also want to have 2 different kernels with different config's.

The Linux kernel is specified in `conf/machine/my-machine.conf`

`PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel ?= 'my-kernel'`which points to `recipe-kernel/linux/my-kernel.bb`

How to include a 2nd development kernel `my-kernel-dev.bb` in the same build config?

Comment: You can search for `KERNEL_PACKAGE_NAME` in [mega manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#)